# How to locate a block with certain text using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

With selenium in python, I want to collect data about a user called "GrahamDumpleton" on the website below:
https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt/graphs/contributors

And this is the block I want to locate with the user name "GrahamDumpleton":
[image]

How to locate this block using selenium?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be clearly done with XPath since XPath is the only approach supporting locating elements based on their text content.
So, that user block element can be located with the following XPath:

```py
//li[contains(@class,'contrib-person')][contains(.,'Graham')]
```

In case you want only the header part of that block this XPath can be used:

```py
//h3[contains(@class,'border-bottom')][contains(.,'Graham')]
```

So, Selenium code returning those elements can be correspondingly

```py
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class,'contrib-person')][contains(.,'Graham')]")
```

And

```py
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//h3[contains(@class,'border-bottom')][contains(.,'Graham')]")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Nice to see you again. May I ask two follow-up questions? 1. I want to find an element under the located header. How could I add this condition? The Xpath is:  //*[@id="contributors"]/ol/li/span/h3/span[2]/span/div/a

Comment: I can answer here, but it would be much better if you can open additional question for that. Stackoverflow rules say: each question should be focused on one, specific problem so it will be more useful for future users.

Comment: 2. I have a list of users like 'Graham', the list is called 'user'. If I want to do a for-loop, could you please provide some hints about how to modify the 'contains' condition? Thanks again!

Comment: Please let me know if you are going to ask a new question or still waiting for my additional explanations here?

Comment: Thanks for reminding, @Prophet, I am waiting for the 90 minutes gap to create a new question. Could you please provide some explanations here? Appreciate it!

Comment: Sure. 1) You can locate element inside element with relative XPath. It should have a dot at the beginning of the XPath. I will show you it in the new question. 2) You can format a string with parameters and then build XPath locater on that XPath. There are similar questions here, but again, when you ask a new, separate question I will try giving more detailed answer with code example there

Comment: Thanks for these helpful explanations! See you in the new question later.